# Array, which is in Object, which is in Array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to take this value

> _wc_deposits_original_total [value] => 828.00

Excatly I mean number "828.00"

I've been trying like this "array[][]" but there's object inside the array and I dont know how to display it.

```
Array(
    [meta_data] => Array (
                [1] => WC_Meta_Data Object (
                        [current_data:protected] => Array (
                            [id] => 12025 
                            [key] => _wc_deposits_original_total 
                            [value] => 828.00 
                        )
                        [data:protected] => Array ( 
                            [id] => 12025 
                            [key] => _wc_deposits_original_total 
                            [value] => 828.00 
                        ) 
                ) 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: you can't access protected object properties directly, so it depends on what the definition of WC_Meta_Data looks like.

Comment: I am not agreed with duplicate question what @deceze suggested. I am agreed with what Jon Stirling says here

Comment: @Alive You need to take the *two* duplicates together.